# Recursively clicking a link to get paginated data

Tags: python, recursion, selenium-webdriver

I am using Selenium with Python. I have to visit a URL, fetch content and click on *next* button to access next page and repeat same. Some how I am not being able to do it recursively and still is accessing first page which does make sense. My Code is given below:

```
def start():
    url = ‘http://example.com/?page=1'
    if driver.find_element_by_class_name('page-link'):
        start()
```

How to make it happen? Should I fetch content of first page, pass data to other method and then call it recursively?

Answer (score 0):

You need to get the new URL and pass it into the start function as an argument. You're resetting the url each time in the first line.

Comment: Issue is that new URL is a JSON structure rather than a simple URL by appending page number in it. I am wondering if there's an alternate route.

Comment: If the new URL indeed contains a json, it most likely contains form data that was passed a long.

Answer (score 0):

I think selenium might be smart to not reload the same url, so you can probably just do the following

```
def start(traversed=False):
    if not traversed:
        url = "http://example.com/?page=1"
    if driver.find_element_by_class_name('page-link'):
        start(traversed=True)
```

OR

```
def start(url=None):
    if not url:
        url = "http://example.com/?page=1"
    if driver.find_element_by_class_name('page-link'):
        start(url=driver.current_url) #browser.current_url
```